# Error: "The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded "

Tags: php, pdo, yum

I am trying to move from a local server to an online server (see error at http://earlysignup.com/ ).  I read online that I should use

```
yum install php-pdo
```

I tried this and I get "No package php-pdo available.".  Can anyone set me straight?

Comment: Find out what the package name is for your distro.

Comment: What distro are you running.  php-pdo is what fedora uses (and thus probably redhat, centos).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open php.ini. The file can be located in the `/etc/php5/cgi` folder, if you're on a Linux server, or some close variation thereof.
2. Uncomment the line `extension=php_pdo.dll` (or `php_pdo.so` if you're on a Linux machine)
3. Uncomment the line (depending on the database you are using) `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` (or `php_mysql_pdo.so`)
4. Restart your webserver and reload the page in question